# Extruding mesh along parametric curve and applying earth curvature?

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm working on a railway generation project, I must generate 3D meshes for the track (rail, ballast, ...). Track origin is defined geographically (latitude/longitude/azimuth/elevation), then the trajectory is defined using curvature (lateral and vertical) values. These curvature values permits to draw the track with three sort of parametric curve : straight lines, circle arc and clothoids (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral).

For now I have a solution working correctly for small tracks, which consists of taking an origin point on the earth (near the track origin) and taking a tangent plane at this location (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates). Then all generation is done on this plane.

But, as one can imagine, on long tracks (several hundreds of kilometers), the meshes don't follow earth curvature. It is thus impossible to match real life datas.

What could be the best solution to address this earth curvature constraint?

Should we always work in spherical coordinate (and thus convert euclidean line/circle/clothoid parametric equation into spherical ones)?

Or could we apply a post transformation to remap meshes on earth?

Comment: how accurate do you need to be? The earth isn't actually spherical and you may need to account for that too

Comment: I would like to find the best accuracy/time performance ratio.
I think I can only afford to compute my curves on the wgs84 ellipsoid, perhaps even only on the sphere (working on the geoid seems to much time consuming).
I don't know if it's even possible to start from a wsg84 geolocated point, follow a curve (defined by lateral and vertical curvature at distances) curved on the earth, and then end on another wgs84 geolocated point.

Comment: Perhaps the best way is it to work on small pieces of plane (projecting geolocated point on them), and manage someway the cross between them.
I have seen that Discrete Global Grid System like ISEA Aperture 3 Hexagon seems interesting (but a bit complicated) perhaps a simple latitude longitude grid could do the job.